# front end, login and backend of Website with laravel 5.6 and vuejs2

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I want to built web site in Laravel and Vuejs. All things are good, but When I use router-view in dashboard it brings all components from webpage. Please help me!
How I can use two template one for website and one for admin dashboard in laravel and vuejs application

Comment: add your code for vuejs and explain what you've tried

Comment: I want have two layout one for website and another for admin dashboard.